# Why lambda here in the code?

Tags: c#, lambda

i found a sample code where lambda was used the code as follows

```
var sumOfgreaterThanSeven = numbers.Sum(n => n > 7 ? n : 0);
```

but the above code can be written as

```
var sumOfgreaterThanSeven = numbers.Sum(n > 7 ? n : 0);
```

so why user write lambda. please help me to understand why user write lambda here.
also tell me what is the advantage of lambda. thanks

Answer (score 12):

The lambda is because you want to evaluate the conditional expression *per item `n`*. The version you added (`Sum(n > 7 ? n : 0)`) can't work - `n` isn't defined anywhere (the compiler message should be "The name 'n' does not exist in the current context").

The lambda can be read as:

> given a term *`n`*, if *`n`* is greater than `7` return *`n`*, else return `0`

and then sum over that logic.

Re the *advantage* - firstly, convenience - but also *composition*. For example, with LINQ-to-SQL I would absolutely expect that to issue something like:

```
 select sum(case when row.col > 7 then row.col else 0 end)
 from sometable row
```

of course, it might be better to use:

```
 var sumOfgreaterThanSeven = numbers.Where(n => n > 7).Sum();
```

which would map to

```
 select sum(row.col)
 from sometable row
 where row.col > 7
```

which might hit an index more accurately

Answer (score 2):

When you write a lambda you are calling a method or evaluating an expression. The left side of the => is a set of parameters passed into the method/expression on the right side.

```
IEnumerableThing.Where(a => DoSomeStuff(a))
```

It's like writing this:

```
foreach (var a in IEnumerableThing)
{
   DoSomeStuff(a);
}
```

In the case of the `Sum()` method you are really doing something like this:

```
int mysum = 0;

foreach (var n in whatever)
{
   if (n > 7) { mysum += n; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to think of Lambda Expressions as methods.

```
n => n > 7 ? n : 0
```

Can in fact be written as

```
(n) => {
    if(n > 7)
        return n;
    else
        return 0;
    }
```

Lambda expression will be converted to **an anonymous method** and an **instance of `Func<>`** will be created from it.

### UPDATE

As Marc pointed out, this conversion to anonymous method and instance of `Func<>` or `Action` does not always happen -as rightly pointed out in Linq-to-sql. ... - but here it does, hence I pointed out the underlying.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it might not; it could be LINQ-to-{SQL|EF|RIA|etc} in which case it is an *expression*, not a delegate / anon-method

Comment: You claim "here it does" - my point: **you don't know that** - `numbers` could easily be `IQueryable<int>`